# Api Version of a UI Component

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developping an application using ActionBarSherlock component. My goal is to target all devices since level 8 API.
I've got an exception on a device running android 2.2.1 (level 8), when I try to inflate the following xml.

I don't know which component isn't ok. Could you guys help me ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/albumImg"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/button" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/albumStatic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Album :"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/albumTitle"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Small"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/albumStatic"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/albumImg"
            android:text="(not found)" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/albumStatic"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Large"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Album :"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/artistStatic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/albumTitle"
            android:text="Artiste : "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/artistName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/albumTitle"
            android:layout_below="@+id/artistStatic"
            android:text="(not found)" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tagsContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/albumImg"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >







        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/tagsScrollView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="32dip"
            android:layout_below="@+id/albumImg"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tagsLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="32dip"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tags_static"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Tags : "
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tags_tv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="(none)" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
        <View
            android:id="@+id/vertical_divider"
            android:layout_width="1dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="16dip"
            android:paddingRight="16dip"
            android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical" />


            <ImageButton

                android:id="@+id/BT_editTags"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="32dip"
                android:paddingLeft="8dip"
                android:paddingRight="8dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />

    </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tracks_static"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tagsContainer"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="Tracks"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/tracksListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tracks_static" >

            <!-- Preview: listitem=@android:layout/simple_list_item_1 -->
        </ListView>



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dateStatic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/albumImg"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/artistName"
            android:text="Date : "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/dateStatic"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dateStatic"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/artistName"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dateStatic"
            android:text="(not found)" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The error log is talking about a scroll bar not found. But I'm pretty sure HorizontalScrollView and listView exists on API 8, don't they ?

Here is the error :

```
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.micky.scanthings/com.micky.scanthings.ScanView}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #121: Error inflating class android.view.View
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2753)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:129)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2117)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4717)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #121: Error inflating class android.view.View
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:544)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:857)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:251)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at com.micky.scanthings.ScanView.onCreate(ScanView.java:58)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2717)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     ... 11 more
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1850)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     ... 25 more
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-hdpi/scrollbar_handle_vertical.9.png from drawable resource ID #0x0
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1714)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1901)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     ... 29 more
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable-hdpi/scrollbar_handle_vertical.9.png
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetNative(Native Method)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset(AssetManager.java:418)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1706)
06-27 17:11:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2064):     ... 31 more
```

**Edit**: This was due to the `?android:attr/dividerVertical` and `?android:attr/dividerVertical` (maybe among other thing, like the Holo theme).

Comment: Also, Holo theme is only available from API 11, so I'm not sure what happens when you run this on API 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the very bottom of the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable-hdpi/scrollbar_handle_vertical.9.png
```

Looks like you're missing a png file in `drawable-hdpi` folder.

Comment: Unlikely.  He'd get a different error then.  Here it's a clean-cut "FileNotFoundException"

Comment: The problem is that I don't habe any scrollbar_handle_vertical.9.png and it has no problem with my ICS device. Could that be because I use some `?android:attr/dividerVertical` in one of my View, and android 2.2 don't know what it is ?

Comment: @MagicMicky yes, that might be the reason.  You are trying to refer to an internal android drawable, which may not exist in lower level API

Comment: Ok, this was something like that. I removed all the occurences of Holo and ?android:attr and it worked fine. I will update to tell which one it was exactly. Thanks